# Get data from text in UTF8 format URL

Tags: java, utf-8

There is a text hosted on a server, in plain text but I try to get that data in UTF-8 format that is able to recognize "ñ" and more. I tried this

```
String readLine;
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://miurl/data.txt");
        BufferedReader in = null;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        while ((readLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
           byte ptext[] = readLine.getBytes(ISO_8859_1); 
           String value = new String(ptext, UTF_8); 
           System.out.println(value);
        }

    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

The problem is that it reads data from url but not encoded as utf8, the letters such as "ñ" are printed strangely.

Comment: what's the problem you are facing in your code?

Comment: The problem is in my question. I get the data but for example the letter ñ me shows it rare.

Comment: @DarkFenix why you are doing this `byte ptext[] = readLine.getBytes(ISO_8859_1); ` ? I mean with this **ISO_8859_1** ? could you post full code ?

Comment: I tried to convert to utf8 the read String. Y es. Is full code

Comment: In what encoding the content is sent? *ISO_8859_1* or *UTF-8*?

Comment: `byte ptext[] = readLine.getBytes(ISO_8859_1);` converts the UTF-8 input into ISO-8859-1 bytes. Then you tell the `String` constructor that it is UTF-8. This is guaranteed to corrupt the data.  It is not clear what you want to do and why you wrote this code. BTW, in this context `ESP:raro --> ENG:strange`.  `ENG:rare --> ESP:poco comun` (I fixed it for you).

Comment: @glee8e The content is in plain text. Txt. I want to convert to Utf8,  Jim thank you. Help me

Comment: Even plain text needs a encoding. Check the `ContentType` header to see if the charset is avaliable.

Comment: That web server don't send it, so you have to figure it out by yourself. If you find it, say you know it's in utf8, then you just use that solution listed below. If you find it in ISO_8859_1, then you use that solution, too, except you will replace the `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"))` with `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "ISO_8859_1"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also had the same issue while reading some special characters from CSV file.
So I used below code to read the files

`BufferedReader bufRdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(userCsv), "ISO-8859-1"));`

In your case you may try

```
URL url = new URL("http://miurl/data.txt");
BufferedReader in = null;
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "ISO-8859-1"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you simply tried this ?

```
        String readLine;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://miurl/data.txt");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"));

            while ((readLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(readline);
            }

        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I tried this on this sample text from [here](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/examples/UTF-8-demo.txt)
and it parses all UTF-8 characters quite okay.

Comment: could you provide the http link of the text file you are trying ? your provided link here is not working.